# How add labelline to Bubble Chart in EChart

Tags: echarts

Because some date are overlap, I want to add labelline in each Bubble, How can I do that? Thks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `label` option to your `series` object:

```
series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    symbolSize: function (data) {
        ...
    },
    emphasis: {
        ...
    },
    label: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top'
    },
    itemStyle: {
        ...
    },
    ...
  }]
```

all the customizations available for this label are here (position, format, etc):
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.label